# How to use Windows UI Automation to push a button with Toggle pattern?

Tags: c#, ui-automation

I am trying to push a button in the Revit interface with the Windows UI Automation. The button is part of a 3-button radio button and has only a TogglePattern. When the Toggle is invoked there is a quick flash where the button seems to be pushed but then it reverts back to its default status. UISpy and the code below both have the same result. Video at https://autode.sk/2DNve7K

```
private static void workplane()
{
    AutomationElement rootElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle(getProcess("revit"));
    AutomationElement StatusBar = getChildElementByAutomationId(rootElement, "Modify_PanelBarScrollViewer");
    AutomationElement button = getChildElementByAutomationId(StatusBar, "Dialog_Essentials_GenhostCreate");
    AutomationElement b2 = getChildElementByAutomationId(button, "_RibbonItemControl");
    AutomationElement b4 = getChildElementByAutomationId(b2, "Dialog_Essentials_GenhostCreate:Control_Essentials_PlaceByWorkplane_RibbonItemControl");
    AutomationElement b5 = getChildElementByAutomationId(b4, "Dialog_Essentials_GenhostCreate:Control_Essentials_PlaceByWorkplane");
    toggleButton(b5);
}

static void toggleButton(AutomationElement button)
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);

    AutomationPattern[] arAp = button.GetSupportedPatterns();
    foreach (AutomationPattern ap in arAp)
    {
        button.TryGetCurrentPattern(ap, out object outObj);
        TogglePattern tp = outObj as TogglePattern;
        if (tp == null)
            continue;
        tp.Toggle();
    }
}

static AutomationElement getChildElementByAutomationId(AutomationElement rootElement, string automationId)
{
    AutomationElement automationElement = rootElement.FindFirst(TreeScope.Children, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.AutomationIdProperty, automationId));
    return automationElement;
}
```

[UISpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBWSd.png)

Comment: Having the same exact problem with Rebar Presentation toggles. Have you ever found a solution to this?